# C2653: not a class or namespace without precompiled headers

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I'm using VisualStudio 2010 to build a simple program with Qt 4.8.3, and i'm having trouble with a simple method definition:

here is my code:

GuiHelper.h

```
#ifndef GUIHELPER_H 
#define GUIHELPER_H

#include "GuiHelper.cpp"
#include <QString>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFile>

class GuiHelper
{
private:
static void useStyleSheet(QString, QWidget*);  
};
#endif //GUIHELPER_H
```

and GuiHelper.cpp:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFile>
#include "GuiHelper.h"

void GuiHelper::useStyleSheet(QString filename, QWidget* widget)
{
// loads style file and apply style
QFile file(":/Resources/"+filename);
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString styleSheet = QLatin1String(file.readAll());
widget->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
}
```

I get the error C2653: GuiHelper is not a class or a namspace but I don't really see what's wrong...

I also checked "no precompiled headers" when creating the project with the QT addin

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quickfix** - remove the

```
#include "GuiHelper.cpp"
```

from the header.

**Cause of the problem**: the compiler compiles the sources - that is the `.cpp` files. It starts parsing the cpp file and reaches

```
#include "GuiHelper.h"
```

which tells it to process the header and paste its contents - the second line of the header does

```
#define GUIHELPER_H
```

Afterwards, you

```
#include "GuiHelper.cpp"
```

which in turn attempts to process and paste the `cpp` file, which again tries to process the header. Because `GUIHELPER_H` was already defined, the header is no longer processed, but remember that the class was not yet defined. So it gets to the line

```
void GuiHelper::useStyleSheet(QString filename, QWidget* widget)
```

but you get the error because `GuiHelper` was not defined yet.

Comment: @BenoitHnte as a rule of thumb, don't include `cpp` files anywhere, unless you're doing bulk builds.